# Youtube api "Invalid entry Id/Uri" with batch request

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working with youtube-api and making the following batch POST-request:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/batch?v=2.1

with the body:

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
      xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
      xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
      xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <batch:operation type="query"/>
  <entry>
    <batch:operation type="query"/>    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/h5jKcDH9s64</id>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

But getting error in the response. Partial response:

```
<title>Error</title>
<content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
<batch:operation type='query'/>
<batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri'/>
```

The single GET-request: 
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/h5jKcDH9s64

works properly.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not POSTing to the correct URL. To do a batch request of video entries, you need to POST to `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/batch?v=2`

The request body should look like

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
      xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
  <batch:operation type="query"/>
  <entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID</id>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID</id>
  </entry>
</feed>
```